# Need assistance with RAZOR

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have list of product, and when I need to edit something I click on button edit at right of product name. How I can I do clickable entire row.

Now I have 
`<td><b>@Html.ActionLink(Products.Resources.Properties.Literals.Edit, "Edit", new { id = items[i].Template.Id })</b></td>`

But I want to do all  clickable.

Comment: You have to attach an event handler to the `<tr>` in javascript. You can still interpolate C# into that JavaScript to provide the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use just a little bit of javascript to do it.

Using pure javascript you can add an event on "tr" element of your html:

```
<tr onclick="document.location='@Url.Action(Products.Resources.Properties.Literals.Edit, "Edit", new { id = items[i].Template.Id })'">
    <td><b>Edit</b></td>...
</tr>
```

In this way the entire row is now clickable. 
Using jquery you can do more:

```
<tr data-link="@Url.Action(...)">
   <td><b>Edit</b></td>
</tr>
```

Your jquery code should look like this:

```
$('tr[data-link]').on('click', function() {
  document.location = $(this).attr('data-link');
});
```

I think the second solution is the most elegant and easiest to implement when needed.

Hope this can help.

Comment: This is incorrect. ActionLink produces an anchor element, so your document.location is going to an `<a>` string. [see](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Rendering/HtmlHelperLinkExtensions.cs)

Comment: You need to bring in the `IUrlHelper` and use the `Action` extension method to produce an absolute path

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. I've made corrections to my answer! Thank you @CallumLinington

Comment: Can I make only something like this <tr @Html.ActionLink(Product.Resources.Properties.Litera‌​ls.Edit, "Edit", new { id = items[i].Template.Id })"> ? I already processed click on Edit, I can just do it over the whole <tr>

Comment: No @Maksims, is not compatible with HTML standards. Please follow my instructions

Comment: Ok,   Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a `click` handler to the `tr` - making the entire `tr` a link would be invalid markup and wouldn't work, anyways.

There are a number of ways to do this and I'm not really sure what your JS setup looks like, so I recommend looking into what your framework/libraries offer (for example, if you're using jQuery, look into something like:

```
$('tr').on('click', function($event) {
    // ...
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't answer all the question - such as, how do you get the link into the javascript...